# Image not uploading in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-upload, django-staticfiles

I am able to update the image of each user's profile picture.
But not through the code. Though it doesn't give me any error.

u_form = For changing the username.
p_form = For changing the picture in their profile.

NOTE: Profile has one to one relation with the Profile model.

**settings.py** file section:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py** for Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpeg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    status = models.TextField(max_length='200')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py for the same:**

```
class ProfileUpdate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image',]
```

Main **views.py** file:

```
.
.
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import  UserCreationForm as uc
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm as af
.
.

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def update_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdate(request.POST, instance=user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdate(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'The profile has been updated.')
            return redirect('/profile')
    else:
        #instance: to get pre-filled data of user
        u_form = UserUpdate(instance=user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdate(instance=user.profile)
        context = {
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
        }
        return render(request, 'update_profile.html', context)
```

HTML form **"update_profile.html":**

```
<form action="{% url 'update_profile' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ u_form }}
    {{ p_form }}
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to pass Profile instance and not User instance
  p_form = ProfileUpdate(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=PROFILE_INSTANCE)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
p_form = ProfileUpdate(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user.profile)
```